# Identify feature which is set for editing

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, editing

While creating custom tool for ArcMap I found problem which couldn't be solved even with try-catch block. When start editing I must to choose which layer I want to edit (if they are from different sources), but if my tool tries to edit other than I've chosen - ArcMap shuts down. How can I identify which layer(s) I can edit?

Comment: How is the layer being identified as the edit layer now (e.g custom user form/selection, named layer in ArcMap, layer on disk)?

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly, but one is car]d workspace and the other is file geodatabase

Answer (score 1):

The [IEditLayers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IEditLayers_Interface/0020000000q8000000/) interface will tell you. This interface is a coclass of IEditor.

The link gives some code on how to use this interface but the guts of it is:

```
//get editor extension
UID editorUID = new UIDClass();
editorUID.Value = "esriEditor.Editor";

IEditor editor = m_application.FindExtensionByCLSID(editorUID) as IEditor; // works but is an old way

// before changing anything
if ((editor as IEditLayers).IsEditable(featureLayerToCheck)) ...
```

This will tell you if the feature layer is editable; before doing this check the state of the [IEditor.EditState](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/EditState_Property/0020000000s9000000/) - if it is anything but 1 then `return;` - no layers will be editable if you aren't editing. Before editing anything in an edit session you should consider start/stop operation which allows the undo:

```
// start operation
editor.StartOperation();

// do your modifications

// finish operation
editor.StopOperation("Text to come up when hovering over undo button");
```

Features that participate in a topology or network must be modified inside an edit operation - if not you will crash ArcMap!

Another way to check if the feature is editable is to use [IWorkspaceEdit](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000m5v000000) - if you are returning feature selection from the map and aren't sure which feature layer they belong to (lazy, but it works) this may be your only hope:

```
IFeatureClass objClass = (myFeature.Class as IFeatureClass); // get the feature class
IWorkspace thisWorkspace = (objClass as IFeatureDataset).workspace; // get the workspace
IWorkspaceEdit thisWorkEdit = (thisWorkspace as IWorkspaceEdit);
if (thisWorkEdit.IsBeingEdited)...
```